# App to allow battery charge only to a certain extent

Tags: software-recommendation, battery

I'd like to charge my rMBP battery only up to 85% or 90%, in order to preserve it.

Is there any app that stops charging at user selected percentages?

If not, is there any other method? (Apart from manually detaching power cable, obviously).

Comment: Buy a plug power timer, work out how long 1 percent takes to charge and then set it to the appropriate time for the current percentage and the needed percentage. The Timers do exist but I have only every found one on sale in a pound (£)  shop once. the timer is like a count down timer (egg time style) not a 24h timer. I use mine for my iron otherwise I will forget to turn it of.

Comment: This one is not from the uk but as an example http://www.hpm.com.au/Products.aspx?pid=422

Comment: What do you mean "preserve it"?

Comment: I mean, to maintain it around 40%, in order to maximize its lifespan..

Comment: Mh, perhaps i found the solution... Excluding the middle pin of magsafe2 (signal) will cause the macbook to user wall power but NOT charge the battery.